# Is there a router or access point which enforces bandwidth limits only when the traffic is high?

Tags: wifi, router, access-point

It seems that in a very large variety of Modem Routers (Wired solutions) or Access point (wireless solutions) there seems to be an option for static and specific limit per user. For example 4Mbps max upload and 10Mbps max upload per user.

However the need here is to have the network device distribute the full range of the available bandwidth to the users. The requirement is that if you have 3 users sharing 30Mbps available from ISP to be able and simultaneously download at 10, 10 and 10 Mbps each, etc. An additional requirement would be to set percentages in that 70% for first and 15% and 15% for the other two would mean that ~21Mbps would be available for first user and the rest of 9 Mbps would be distributed evenly among second and a third user. Note that if the first two users have disconnected then third user is expected to happily enjoy the full speed of 30Mbps

Are there solutions that are offering something similar to the above scenario ?
Many thanks

Comment: If you don't use any QoS functionality at all you should get an even split between all of the computers while allowing all computers to use up to the whole bandwidth when others aren't. Your second "rule" where you assign 70% of the traffic to one computer would be possible on most routers that have priority-based QoS controls, but it is mutually exclusive with your first "rule". A router can't guess how you are going to want to split the bandwidth, so you must enter that manually into the QoS settings every time you want to change it. In your case toggling the QoS on and off may be useful.

Comment: Thanks @Romen tried QoS setup at a DLink router here and this ignored my setup completely. One port had highest priority, and some other port had lowest priority. However on stress seemed that both are downloading/uploading with the same speed